# Graph.Read_Ncol (csv) for igraph in Python

Tags: python, csv, igraph

I'm completely new to coding and Python and am having trouble with the simple task of reading a csv file.

Naturally, I started with:

```
import pandas as pd
import igraph as ig
```

I tested the csv using:

```
test_df = pd.read_csv('griplinks.csv')
print(test_df.head())
```

It seemed to work because I was able to come up with the output:

> ```
>    From  To
> 0     1  11
> 1     1  31
> 2     1  40
> 3     1  44
> 4     1  53
> ```

However, when it was time to actually read my csv file using:

```
griplinks = ig.Graph.Read_Ncol('griplinks.csv', directed=False)
```

I would come up with:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 1 # Attempt 1
> 2
> ----> 3 griplinks = ig.Graph.Read_Ncol('griplinks.csv', directed=False)
>
> InternalError: Error at
> c:\users\vssadministrator\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-ft6_7fco\vendor\build\igraph\igraph-0.8.3-msvc\src\foreign.c:244:
> Parse error in NCOL file, line 1 (syntax error, unexpected NEWLINE,
> expecting ALNUM), Parse error

Since nothing's really wrong with my csv file or its path, I was wondering if there's something wrong with the code I used to read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is indeed not really clear: it is expected that the nodes are separated by whitespace, not by a comma. It might be easier to actually construct your graph from the pandas [dataframe](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#DataFrame):

```py
griplinks = ig.Graph.DataFrame(test_df)
```

Note that this was only introduced in `python-igraph` version 0.8.3, so make sure to use at least that version.

Comment: Can you pls clarify the docs a bit? The best indicator that improvements are needed are user questions like this.

Comment: I do have the python-igraph version 0.8.3 so I still find it odd that the Read_Ncol didn't work. But I managed to construct the graph using the dataframe, as you suggested. So thank you!

Comment: I got this working by adding the argument `use_vides=False`. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73961372/source-and-target-ids-must-be-0-based-integers-found-types-dtypeo-dtype