# PageRank clustering on Cytoscape using subgraph

Tags: python, graph, igraph, cytoscape

I have a `df` that ranks the `Importance` of `TF` and `Target` networks in descending order.
I generated a subgraph of the top 1% network using Python iGraph and wrote it into a graphml file. Then, I feed the subgraph into Cytoscape, where I want to perform Page Rank (or Random Walk) clustering algorithm using the ClusterMaker app.

The Cytoscape software generated a network without any labeling or ranking. Which part of my code is wrong?

```
import igraph as ig
from igraph import Graph
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
import numpy as np
```

Encoding:

```
enc = OrdinalEncoder()
df.iloc[:,0:2] = enc.fit_transform(df.iloc[:,0:2])
df.iloc[:,0:2] = df.iloc[:,0:2].astype(int)
```

Graph generation code:

```
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
G = Graph.TupleList(tuples, directed=True, edge_attrs=['Importance'])
G.es["TF"] = df["TF"]
G.es["Target"] = df["Target"]
```

subgraph generation code:

```
btwn = G.betweenness(weights='Importance')
ntile = np.percentile(btwn, 99)
pruned_vs = G.vs.select([v for v, b in enumerate(btwn) if b >= ntile])
pruned_graph = G.subgraph(pruned_vs)
pruned_graph.write_graphml("pruned_topgenes_directed_networks.graphml")
```

Data:

`df.head()`

```
pd.DataFrame({'TF': {0: 'ZFY', 1: 'ZFY', 2: 'ZFY', 3: 'ZFY', 4: 'ZFY'},
 'Target': {0: 'DDX3Y', 1: 'EIF1AY', 2: 'CYorf15A', 3: 'USP9Y', 4: 'KDM5D'},
 'Importance': {0: 271.64476419966564,
  1: 249.63252368981105,
  2: 249.47948849863877,
  3: 242.14502589211688,
  4: 215.67076799218304}})
```

Current output:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's hard for me to see exactly what's going on here. But I can make a couple suggestions.

1. The blurry blob you see in Cytoscape may partly be due to a default graphic detail threshold (for interactive performance). The pixelated diamond icon in the network toolbar (just below network) will toggle this setting.
2. I'd recommend going straight from igraph to cytoscape using https://py4cytoscape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. This way you remove whatever might be going on with the graphml step. BTW, you can also go straight from a df to Cytoscape using this package as well.